# Good application to render or convert SVG files to other file formats

Tags: images, conversion, graphics, rendering, svg

I need to render SVG files to other file formats (.png, for example.)  What's a good application for performing that render or conversion?

Specifically, I need an application that runs on Windows.
I'd welcome suggestions for other platforms, as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) can export SVG to bitmap formats.

Comment: Agreed, Inkscape is a great choice for this.  Specifically, you'll need to open the .svg file, go to File -> Export Bitmap (or hit Ctrl+Shift+E), select your options, and click Export.

Comment: You can also rasterize SVG to PNG from the command line, and the results are nicer looking than Batik too.

Answer (score 5):

If you're on Linux  (Ubuntu) use: [rsvg-convert](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=820965)

Answer (score 4):

[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) or [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) are usually very good at converting SVG to other formats.

Opening the SVG file in GIMP will cause it to ask you what size (resolution) to treat the file as to convert to a bitmap style image. You can then save it as you like.

Inkscape is a Vector editor, from which you can export to a plethora of formats. Open the file then select File > Export Bitmap.

Answer (score 3):

The industry standard vector app is [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator/). It's pricy, but robust and stuffed with pro grade features.

Comment: You don't need illustrator to render an svg.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will work for ordinary (non-animated) SVGs. If your SVG is **animated**, you need to pick a frame-rate (since SVG animation is time-based whereas most other formats are frame-based), export frames, and convert the frames to your desired format. See [Convert animated SVG to movie](https://superuser.com/questions/48532/convert-animated-svg-to-movie) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Found this using Inkscape via http://gastarbeiten.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/batch-convert-svg-to-png-with-inkscape-command-line/

```
$ cd your-directory-with-the-svgs/
$ for i in *; do inkscape $i --export-png=`echo $i | sed -e 's/svg$/png/'`; done
```

HTH