# Convert animated SVG to animated GIF?

Tags: macos, images, svg, gif, animated-gif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert animated SVG to movie](https://superuser.com/questions/48532/convert-animated-svg-to-movie)

Is it possible to convert an animated SVG-image to an animated GIF?

I have seen this question [Convert animated SVG to movie](https://superuser.com/questions/48532/convert-animated-svg-to-movie) but "Squiggle" only work on windows.

How can I do this on a mac?

Alternate just a way to export every frame of the SVG, and I can then assemble it myself into an animated GIF.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Batik Squiggle is a cross platform application written in Java. There is even a installer for OS X: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/browser.html