# SVG to JPEG/BMP conversion

Tags: images, conversion, jpeg, svg, bmp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good application to render or convert SVG files to other file formats](https://superuser.com/questions/31400/good-application-to-render-or-convert-svg-files-to-other-file-formats)

I have an SVG file that I want to convert to JPEG or BMP (or any other image formats).

All the conversions that I have used on the various online tools yielded very unclear output images.

I don't want to use SVG as it is very inconvenient.

What do you suggest to get around that?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/31400/what-is-a-good-application-to-render-svg-files-to-other-file-formats